# after navigating usring f:event preRenderView the next page does not show menus properly

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces v4.0. I have an f:event listener={..} type=preRenderView set in my xhtml. The listener method is also called correctly,but this listener method performs Navigation using Navigation handler. What is observe is that after the navigation is complete and the 2nd page is loaded, the menus of the second page are not showing as expected. Seems there is some css/js not loading. Below is my xhtml template which has the menu code.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                >       


    <h:head>
            <f:facet name="first">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8" />
                <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>CBB-Questionnaire</title>
            </f:facet>

            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{resource['css:template.css']}" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body >
           <p:tooltip /> 

                    <div class="qestDiv" >
            <div class="header">
                           <h:form id="homeform"> 
                            <p:menubar >  
                                <p:submenu label="Questionnaire" icon="ui-icon-document" >  
                                    <p:menuitem value="Technology Outsourcing" action="TechQuestionnaireForOutSrc"  
                                        icon="ui-icon-document" id="TECHQ1"
                                        actionListener="#{usersession.questSelectedSetInSession}"/>  
                                </p:submenu>  
                            </p:menubar>       
                           </h:form>
                        </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="centerpane">
                                    <div class="pageContent">
                                        <ui:insert name="pageContent" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer">
                    </div>
    </h:body>
</html>



page1.xhtml is below navigates to page2.xhtml  

    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      >
    <ui:define name="pageContent" >

        <f:event listener="#{techQOutSrcbean.checkSubmissionStatusAndNavigate}" type="preRenderView" />    
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition> 

page2.xhtml

     <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      >

    <ui:define name="pageContent" >
</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

When page2.xhtml loads it is supposed to show the menus defined in teh template as i am using facelets. But the menus in page2 loads, but it is loaded as

[image]

[image]

Below is the html source which tells that the js is not loaded on the page where the menu is loaded incomplete.

```
            <!-- taken from the page where menu loads properly -->
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>CBB-Questionnaire</title><link href="/QuestionaireWeb/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link href="/QuestionaireWeb/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><script src="/QuestionaireWeb/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/QuestionaireWeb/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/QuestionaireWeb/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="/QuestionaireWeb/faces/javax.faces.resource/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


            <!-- taken from the page where js/css does not load properly fro the menu -->
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>CBB-Questionnaire</title><link href="/QuestionaireWeb/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link href="/QuestionaireWeb/faces/javax.faces.resource/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a `type` attribute in your `f:event`? That will make the listener be invoked for all the events happening. Also using view event listeners for navigation is just wrong in JSF. Don't know where you've seen that, but should forget about it as soon as possible.

Comment: i have already set type attribute as preRenderView. If you scroll to right you will notice it. i am using f:event for checking and navigating. if this is wrong way , then pls help me with some suggestions on how to navigate to page2 from page1, where page1 before loading checks a condition and if false then navigates to page2

Comment: Which are the conditions to be tested? Do you have view params or something like that? What is what you want to be validated?

Comment: page1.xhtml shows a tabview with 5 tabs, each tab has a h:form. On page1 on the click of "Submit" btn, i am marking the set of forms as "submitted" in my DB. Now next time if a user clicks on the page1 from the menu shown in screenshot, then he should be redirected to page2 which displays a message saying "Already Submitted". So how can i call some method of my bean when page1 loads to check if form submitted flag in DB. If true then redirect to page2. Note that my current problem is i guess related to css/js not loading. Pls see screenshot#2

Comment: Even unrelated to the problem, that's not a proper place for doing it. Instead of having a link to page1 directly, you should call a controller method in order to evaluate the outcome for your current request (which will be page1 or page2). If you want to maintain it as a plain link without having to perform a *POST* request, evaluate if user has filled the form and display it as something like that: `h:link outcome="#{sessionController.formFilled ? 'page2' : 'page1'}"`. Related to the styles, try to provide your custom stylesheet in the JSF way, using `h:outputStylesheet`.

Comment: ok, i will try as suggested and will revert asap.

Comment: @XtremeBiker - my menuitem in the template.xhtml which actually outputs link is now modified to have action="..checkFormFille...". So it is now navigating to page2.xhtml and the menu loads correctly with css. But now how can i restrict the user from directly calling page1.xhtml as page1.xhtml should not be accessible since the form is already submitted. I dont want to use request filters coz then for each page i have to code in the filter. Any suggestions ?

Comment: In order to secure the access the best way to do is with request filters. If not, you'll need an event before rendering the page, you can do it with `preRenderView` and throw an exception if user hasn't got access permission.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I tried using an event with type preRenderView, but again i land into same problem of css/js not loading the menu of nagivated page. Doi have only request filters as the last option. ?

Comment: also the same problem exists if i use a navigation handler and navigate. css/js still does not load

Comment: About css issue, it probably is your own css styles crashing with PF ones. Have a look at how to override them : http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-override-primefaces-css/

Comment: Infact the css error persists even after i completely remove my overridden css from the head. what is observe from the IE Debugger is that the jquery js are not present in the head once the css problem arises during navigation